# UIViewController with index

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have used before the method:

```
self.viewController1 = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil andID:0];
```

But I tried to use it again and it doesn't auto-fills the method with the ID and stops at the bundle. I tried to fill the "andID" myself and it doesn't work, like they deleted this function or something.

Any ideas how can I achieve the ID in the viewController? Or maybe other ideas how to recognize same classes and load them with different data.

Thanks!

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to do exactly. What are you using this ID for?

Answer (score 2):

That is not a standard `UIViewController` method. The standard one is:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle
```

.. you've probably been using a custom method which is now missing from your `MyViewController` implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add that method on your `MyViewController` class.

So, you need to add a method declaration and its relative implementation.

```
//MyViewController.h
@interface MyViewController
{
   int _controllerId;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) int controllerId;

@end

//MyViewController.m
@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize controllerId = _controllerId;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle andId:(int)contrId
{
   if(self = [super initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nibBundle])
   {
      self.controllerId = contrId;
   }

   return self;
}

@end
```

Now you can create an instance of `MyViewController` class like the following.

```
MyViewController myController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil andID:0];
self.viewController1 = myController;
[myController release]; // if viewController1 has a retain policy
```

I suggest you to not alloc-init and assign a new instance to a property in the same line. In fact, if your property viewController1 has a retain policy you create a memory leak. In alternative:

```
self.viewController1 = [[[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil andID:0] autorelease]; // if viewController1 has a retain policy
```

**Some notes**

Since `initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle` is a public method you could call it without passing an id for your new method. To avoid this you can turn  `(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle andId:(int)contrId` as the designated initializers. In this manner you cannot create a controller without an id.